# Storage of adhoc data in WCF Request Context

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

In ASP.NET, if you have an HTTP Module or something similar, you can add additional data to the request context before the request actually gets serviced by the end application using the following:

```
HttpContext.Current.Items
```

Is there a similar place (*or pattern*) for storing adhoc data in the WCF Request Pipeline? Basically, I have custom message inspectors and behaviours that need to be able to communicate small pieces of state to the servicing application.

Ideally there is a solution for .NET 3.5.

Comment: Maybe you can provide an example to make this clearer?

Comment: Why not just pass the state info in parameters as part of the service method call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use message properties for that (they's essentially a dictionary). In the inspectors you can add them directly to the message. On the operation you can get the properties via the OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties.

If you want to pass data from the operation to some inspectors which are looking at the response, you'd use the OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties.